Discard millisecond part from timestamp when defining schema with @dsnp/parquetjs library
I want to define a parquet schema using @dsnp/parquetjs library.
One of the fields of the Schema needs to be in Timestamp without milliseconds (Unix timestamp for instance).
The only available timestamp types in this library are TIMESTAMP_MILLIS and TIMESTAMP_MICROS.
Do you have some workaround solutions?
Here is my code so far
export const mySchema = new ParquetSchema({
  creationDate: {
    type: 'TIMESTAMP_MILLIS', // I need it without milliseconds part
    optional: true,
  },
  // ... other fields
});

